# error: forward declaration, how to access pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, forward-declaration

I'm doing a small program, just to play with classes. 
And I've made two classes, a and b.

I want to be able to access a in b and vice versa.
This is what I got so far:

```
#ifndef A_HH_
#define A_HH_

#include <string>

class b;

class a
{
private:
    string aString;
    b* bClass;
public:
    a(){aString = "A";}
    string getString(){return aString;}
    string getBString(){return bClass->bString;}
};


#endif /* A_HH_ */
```

and b:

```
#ifndef B_HH_
#define B_HH_

#include <string>

class a;

class b
{
private:
    string bString;
    a* aClass;
public:
    b(){bString = "B";}
    string getString(){return bString;}
};


#endif /* B_HH_ */
```

I want to be able to access the pointer not just store it.
How can I do that?

Comment: You can use a forward declaration in the header, but then put the implementation of the functions in a cpp file where you can include both headers.  Doing it inline like you have requires the full class structure to be available which you can't have because of the circular include problem.

Comment: What do you mean? Which pointer? From a designing point of view it's usually not a good practice to have two classes have this kind of two way relationship

Comment: Note that circular and/or mutual dependencies are generally considered bad.  So now (thanks to @RetiredNinja) you know how to do this, **don't**!  :-)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you *use* the `bClass` pointer in class `a`, for that you need the definition of class `b`. In this case this can be solved by simply including `b.hh` in `a.hh`. This simple solution will work as you're only declaring an `a` pointer (but don't access it) in the class `b`. A forward declaration is not enough, because it doesn't actually tells the compiler anything more than that the class `b` exist.

Oh, and you need to change the `bClass->bString` in `a::getBString` to `bClass->getString()`, as `b::bString` is private. And of course create an actual instance of `b` and assign it to `bClass`.

Answer (score 0):

In short, to access members of a struct or a class, you need to meet two conditions:

1. the accessing element (class, method, ...) must have access "rights" to the referenced member
2. the definition of the struct/class must be available.

To overcome 1. you can either make the member public, or declare the accessing class or method as `friend`, or better use a getter method.
To overcome 2., you need to include the header of the referenced class.

Answer (score 0):

You might use templating:

for a:

```
#ifndef A_HH_
#define A_HH_

#include <string>
#include "b.h"


class a
{
private:
    string aString;
    b* bClass;
public:
    a()
    {
        aString = "A";
        bClass = new b<a>;
    }
    string getString(){return aString;}
    string getBString(){return bClass->getString();}
};


#endif /* A_HH_ */
```

and for b:

```
#ifndef B_HH_
#define B_HH_

#include <string>

template <typename T>
class b
{
private:
    string bString;
    T* aClass;
public:
    b()
    {
        bString = "B";
        aClass = new T;
    }
    string getString(){return bString;}
    string getAString(){return aClass->getString();}
};


#endif /* B_HH_ */
```

This removes the circular dependency